# React Apollo subscription bypasses the graphql wrapper

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I have a sample app called [GraphQL Bookstore](https://github.com/archfirst/graphql-bookstore-client) that creates books, publishers and authors and shows relationships between them. I am using subscriptions to show updates in real time.

For some reason my `BOOK_ADDED` subscription is bypassing the `graphql` wrapper completely. It is calling the wrapped class with the `books` prop set to `undefined`. Relevant parts of the code are shown below (you can see the full code [here](https://github.com/archfirst/graphql-bookstore-client/blob/master/src/features/bookstore/books/books-container.js)).

```
class BooksContainerBase extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const { subscribeToMore } = this.props;
        subscribeToMore({
            document: BOOK_ADDED,
            updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
                if (!subscriptionData.data) {
                    return prev;
                }

                const newBook = subscriptionData.data.bookAdded;

                // Don't double add the book
                if (!prev.books.find(book => book.id === newBook.id)) {
                    return Object.assign({}, prev, {
                        books: [...prev.books, newBook]
                    });
                } else {
                    return prev;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { books } = this.props;
        return <BooksView books={books} />;
    }
}

...

export const BooksContainer = graphql(BOOKS_QUERY, {
    props: ({ data: { loading, error, subscribeToMore, books } }) => ({
        loading,
        error,
        subscribeToMore,
        books
    })
})(LoadingStateViewer(BooksContainerBase));
```

Basically when a subscription notification is received by the client, the `updateQuery()` function is called - as expected. However, as soon as that function exits, the `render()` method of the wrapped class is called directly with `books` set to `undefined`. I expected that the `graphql` wrapper would be called, setting the props correctly before calling the `render()` method. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!